# Are boys fussier than girls?

Tags: infant

Ever since we announced we were going to have a second and it came out it was going to be a boy, I was relentlessly told that "boys are fussier than girls" when they are a baby. I wasn't inclined to believe such nonsense. It was all anecdotal evidence seasoned with the classic "everyone knows that..." *argumentum ad populum*.

Our boy was born and he is definitely more fussy than our daughter was. At the same time, he is also less colicky than she was. They were/are both healthy babies, growing normally, getting fed, clothed, and changed but it seems like, while she was able to be alone by herself for periods of time while we finished up the dishes or hung the laundry, he cannot stand being putting down.

Keeping in mind that fussy, in this instance, is clearly defined as "fastidious about one's needs" and "hard to please" do studies exist that investigate the idea that boys tend to require more attention from a parent while girls require less? If they do, what was the conclusion of that study?

Comment: Everyone's different.  Some infants, regardless of sex, are very fussy.  Some are absolutely not.  My brother and I (boys) as infants were apparently not fussy at all.  A few of my cousins (girls) were very fussy.

Comment: How do you objectively measure fussiness?

Comment: @Beofett, maybe needy is a better word.

Comment: @Beofett - decibels?

Comment: Are you speaking specifically of infants?  Or boys vs. girls up through their teens?

Comment: Question: "Are boys fussier than girls?"    Question body caveat: "without relying completely on anecdotal evidence but rather real, scientific research, is this true?". I laughed.

Comment: @Noah - I found studies

Comment: @DVK Props for research on crying frequency and colic, but "fussy" is ill-defined in this question and not quantifiable in the context of the question.

Comment: @Noah, "fussy" is clearly defined and also quantifiable. Length of time before requiring parental attention, time it takes to console, the reason for needing to be consoled, frequency. I'd say those are pretty good metrics to start with. I've updated my questions to clarify what I am looking for.

Comment: @ChristopherW Thanks for clarifying! (I just had a conversation about this with my wife today, about the definition of fussy)

Comment: Note that you will observe a difference between the first and second child merely because he is the second.  It is likely that when you had only one, that child received more attention without having to ask for it, while the second child will typically receive less attention than the first did at the same age, and may need to call for it more frequently. I would expect this effect to swamp any gender differences. That being said, each child is very different, and you will find people that say their first child, a girl, was more difficult than their second child, a boy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shergill-Bonner, R (2010). "Infantile colic: practicalities of management, including dietary aspects.". The journal of family health care 20 (6): 206–9. PMID 21319674:

> Colic... occurring at the same rate in boys and in girls (cite via Wikipedia)

---

[Another one](http://www.smartparenting.com.ph/home-living/homebase/do-young-boys-cry-more-than-young-girls):

> According to a 2010 study by Miranda A. L. Van Tilburg, Marielle L. Unterberg, and Ad J. J. M. Vingerhoets, published in the British Journal of Developmental Psychology, no difference in terms of crying frequency can be noted among babies and young children.

Comment: However, see this interesting study: http://clinmed.netprints.org/cgi/content/full/2000080008v1

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I have no studies, only my own example...

I have two girls and one boy.  The boy as a baby was exhausting!  I basically carried him around everywhere for six months without putting him down (thanks baby wrap!), he would be upset for the slightest thing, he didn't like car, he didn't dark, he didn't like mummy sleeping. Let's face it, he was a pain. >.<

But now he is the nicest of all. A sweet smart cheerful boy.

My two girls were nice easily-contented baby, especially the last one. That last girl was a dream of a baby.  No lies, she started to sleep through the night when she was three week old.  She would be happy in anyone's arms, she didn't mind playing alone when mummy was cooking, she didn't mind the car, she didn't mind going to day care, she was a smily easy baby.  And now (she is three) she is a little monster. >.<

It's hard, but your boy will grow fast.